# Microsoft Dynamics CRM 4.0 and Identity Lifecycle Management

Tags: identity, dynamics-crm, lifecycle, microsoft-dynamics

Customers are stored in Dynamics CRM 4.0 an some need access to external facing application and therefore should be provisioned in the DMZ Active Directory.

Does it make sense to use MS Identity Management Lifecycle to push the accounts in the DMZ Active Directory?

Answer (score 0):

I would say that if you had bigger plans for maintaining the DMZ Active Directory with a number of sources of information, then I would go for MS ILM/FIM.

But, just to push users into AD from CRM by an event (e.g. flipping a RequiresADAccount bit on systemuser), I would go with some custom code to provision those users (System.DirectoryServices).